# Error en dirección de audio.wav con la clase AudioClip

Tags: java

No entiendo que pasa con la dirección, la coloque en la carpeta del proyecto y la pase como parametro por su nombre (el archivo .wav se llama "AdventuresAHitmitsu.wav"), tambien intento estando dentro de un paquete llamado src.sounds haciendo referencia así "src.sounds/AdventuresAHitmitsu.wav" y nada :( No entiendo que pasa.  El error que genera es NullPointerException...

import java.applet.AudioClip;
/**
 *
 * @author Victor
 */
public class Musica {

```
AudioClip audio_clip;

public Musica(String ruta){
    try {
        audio_clip = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource(ruta));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problema con dirección de la música");
    }
}

public void playMusic() {
    audio_clip.play();
    audio_clip.loop();
}

public void stopMusic() {
    audio_clip.stop();
}
```

}
Árbol de carpetas en el proyecto Netbeans
Proyecto{
-> clases{Musica, y, z}
-> sonidos{-> sonido.wav}
-> ui {Principal.java,y,z}
-> imagenes{x,y,z}
}
La ruta que tengo es "sonidos/sonido.wav" simplemente. Esta la coloco como   parametro de mi clase música y ahí me tira el error. Donde intento hacer la   asignación es en la clase "Principal.java" del paquete ->ui
public Principal() {
        initComponents();
        Principal.music = new Musica("AdventuresAHimitsu.wav");
        Principal.music.playMusic();
}

Comment: Victor, por favor usa ctrl+k para formatear el código de tu pregunta, o usa los controles de edición cuando estés editando tu pregunta. Revisa esta [respuesta en el Meta de Stack Overflow en Español](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78) para conocer cómo puedes editar el código de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es probablemente la ruta `src.sounds/AdventuresAHitmitsu.wav`.

Si tu estructura de carpetas es `src/sounds/AdventuresAHimitsu.wav` desde la carpeta de tu código fuente, quieres usar `"/src/sounds/AdventuresAHimitsu.wav" como ruta.

Comment: Nada amigo, no entiendo que pasa. Hice la ruta más simple, probé en otro proyecto y funciona el sonido.

Comment: Podrías agregar un arbol de carpetas de tu proyecto marcando donde guardas los recursos? Como el método debería funcionar, no estoy seguro si me quedó claro como exactamente definiste tus rutas.